# Rails templates documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot find rails template documentation. Where can I find it?

In my case I search for 'if'-keyword syntax, but I will be thankful if you show me where I can find this type of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for basic info of how to do ERB? If so, here are some samples on the [ruby-doc site](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html).

Here's an example of an if-statement in ERB:

```
      <% if @cost < 10 %>
        <b>Only <%= @cost %>!!!</b>
      <% else %>
         Call for a price, today!
      <% end %>
```

Comment: Is ERB default template engine in Rails?

Comment: Yes, but you can add haml pretty easily. I use haml (just add `gem 'haml'` to your Gemfile and name them `filename.html.haml` instead of `filename.html.erb`.